# cron file_get_contents() error

Tags: php, command-line, cron

I have a php file which uses `file_get_contents()`

It works fine in the browser, but fails with the following error when run as a cron job:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server
>   configuration in
>   /path/to/the/phpfile.php on line 22

This is what I'm using:

> /usr/bin/php5 -q
>   /path/to/the/phpfile.php

Iv'e already set `allow_url_fopen = true` in php.ini but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Everything works perfectly in the browser though. How can this be fixed?

Comment: are you reading from secure protocal that is https?

Comment: No, its a http API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading a file from a remote system, you should be using curl instead. file_get_contents doesn't handle network delays, redirects or error capture. And is obviously disable in the server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do `php --info | more`
2. run and see which php.ini it uses (top 5 lines)
3. change **that** php.ini file

Or you can use the `--php-ini /path/to/ini`  (do `man php`) to specify the ini file you want to use.

Comment: I feel that merging my answer into yours would make for a fairly complete answer :)

Comment: php --info " more showed - /usr/local/php-5.2.6-1/etc/php.ini. But I cannot locate that folder?

Comment: I have access to /home/my_site_folder but I don't see /usr anywhere. Does this mean I wont be able to change the php.ini file?

Answer (score 1):

At least some Linux distributions have multiple PHP configurations (php.ini files).
For example, Debian testing has these two:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

In the example above different PHP configurations are used for web invocation (via apache) and for command-line invocation.

This *might* be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might unintentionally have more than one copy of PHP and/or php.ini on the system. Do you have admin rights on the PC? Do a global search for `php` and see what turns up.

Comment: This is WRT my web server and I don't have access to the PC. by "copy of PHP" do you mean different versions of PHP?

Comment: I meant either different installations, different versions, or different config files. For example, chronos's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use php -q  use php -cron  in your cron configuration.
It works for me.